# binary tree in c++ for adding strings with frequency of words

Tags: c++, string, binary-search-tree

I'm learning c++ and i get assigned as a project to build a tree that given a string(e.g. "hello world hello one world"), it has to create a node for each different word in the string, and part of the node must contain an space to save the word and another to save the frequency of appearance (e.g. hello|2, one|1, world|2), but when i put the words individually with the meter() function there is no problem, but the problem is when i'm trying to get the words for a whole string, for some strange reason is just adding to the tree the last word of the string with frequency the number of words in the string. I already tried different methods to split the string in words to add them to the tree but all this methods always get me this same result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef char* tipo;
typedef int tipo1;

class Nodo{
  tipo1 f;
  tipo dato;
  Nodo *izq;
  Nodo *der;
  friend class Arbol;
};

typedef Nodo* pNodo;

class Arbol{
      pNodo raiz;
      public:
             Arbol();
             pNodo getRaiz();
             tipo getDato();
             void insertarNodo(tipo x, pNodo &p);
             void meter(tipo x);
             void eliminaNodo(tipo x, pNodo &p);
             void eliminar(tipo x);
             void inOrden(pNodo p);
             tipo1 pertenece(tipo x, pNodo p);
             tipo menor(pNodo p);
             tipo1 pertenece1(tipo x);
             int estaVacia();
             void arbolito(tipo x);
};

Arbol::Arbol(){
        raiz=NULL;
}

pNodo Arbol:: getRaiz(){
      return raiz;
}

int Arbol:: estaVacia(){
    return raiz==NULL;
}

void Arbol::insertarNodo(tipo x, pNodo &p){
     if (p==NULL){
        p=new Nodo();
        p->f=1;
        p->dato=x;
        p->izq=NULL;
        p->der=NULL;
     }
     else if(strcmp(x, p -> dato)<0){
          insertarNodo(x, p->izq);
     }
     else if(strcmp(x, p -> dato)>0){
          insertarNodo(x,p->der);
     }
     else if(strcmp(x, p -> dato)==0){
          p -> f ++;
     }
}

void Arbol:: meter(tipo x){
     insertarNodo(x,raiz);
}

tipo Arbol:: menor(pNodo p){
     if (estaVacia()){
                      return "Error: Arbol vacio";
     }else{
           if (p->izq==NULL){
                             return p->dato;
           }else{
                 return menor(p->izq);
           }
     }
}

void Arbol:: eliminaNodo(tipo x, pNodo &p){
     if (p!=NULL){
                  if (strcmp(x, p -> dato)==0){
                     (p->f)--;
                     if (p->izq==NULL && p->f==0){
                                       pNodo q=p;
                                       p=p->der;
                                       delete q;
                     }else if(p->der==NULL && p->f==0){
                           pNodo q=p;
                           p=p->izq;
                           delete q;
                     }else if(p->izq!=NULL && p->der!=NULL & p->f==0){
                           tipo m=menor(p->der);
                           p->dato=m;
                           eliminaNodo(m,p->der);
                     }
                  }else if (strcmp(x, p -> dato)<0){
                        eliminaNodo(x,p->izq);
                  }else{
                        eliminaNodo(x, p->der);
                  }
     }else{
           cout<<"No se encontro el dato";
     }
}

void Arbol:: eliminar(tipo x){
     eliminaNodo(x, raiz);
}

void Arbol:: inOrden(pNodo p){
     if (p!=NULL){
                  inOrden(p->izq);
                  cout<<p->dato<<"="<<p->f<<endl;
                  inOrden(p->der);
     }
}

tipo1 Arbol:: pertenece(tipo x, pNodo p){
    if (p==NULL){
                 return 0;
    }
    if (p->dato==x){
                    return p->f;
    }else if(strcmp(x, p -> dato)<0){
          return pertenece(x, p->izq);
    }else if(strcmp(x, p -> dato)>0){
          return pertenece(x,p->der);
    }
}

tipo1 Arbol:: pertenece1(tipo x){
      return pertenece(x,raiz);
}

int main()
{
    Arbol tree;
    tipo a,b;
    string x;
    string s="hjk This is";
    s=s+" ";
    int i=0;
    a=strchr(s.c_str(),' ');
    while (s[i]!=' ' && i<s.size()){
          x=x+s[i];
          i++;
          if (i==a-s.c_str()){
             strcpy(b, x.c_str());
             cout <<x.c_str()<<endl;
             tree.meter(b);
             i++;
             a=strchr(a+1,' ');
             x="";
          }
    }
    tree.inOrden(tree.getRaiz());
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use std::string.  See all its members, especially `find_first` and `substr`.

Comment: For C-Style strings, look at the functions `strchr` and `strstr`.

Comment: The problem is not getting the words, (i already split the string and get the words), the problem is when i use the meter() function, because the function reads all the words individually but just returns the last one when i print it with the inOrden() function. But thanks for the help.

Comment: CanI ask why you need a tree structure for this? A simple list (or linked list) of words would be good enough. Or is it because you need to learn about binary searches?

Comment: Is a project for a my class of data structures, and we are learning binaty searches. And yeah it would be easier to build a list for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because you are using `char*` and not strings.

When you insert a node in to your data structure you only keep a copy of the *pointer* to the string, and do not take a copy of the string.

When your code parses the next word in the sentence you assign the new word to the pointer `b`. Then *all* your nodes now point to the same word - which after you have processed the sentence will always be the last one.

Change your code to use `strcpy` to take a copy of the word and store it in the node, not just a copy of the pointer. (don't forget to allocate memory for the copy, another reason to change to using `string` and not `char*`, all the memory management is handled for you.)

Comment: Now that you say it. It really seems that is the problem, I'm gonna try to solve it, thanks.

Comment: @JorgeRamos - I can't stress enough how much you should change from `char*` to `string`. You tagged your question `C++` so there's no reason not to use the libraries available to make things easier. If you want to stick with `char*` then don't use `typedef`; when learning to code it can mask when you need to do a copy instead of assignment, as in this case. Good luck!

Comment: If you need to duplicate your strings, `strdup` is your friend. The ultimate choice of language is yours, but my advice would be to stick to C strings just as an exercise. Of course std::strings are easier to use, but you might learn something valuable from getting to grips with what goes on behind the scene.